# Alternate to mysqli_num_rows for this php script

Tags: php, mysql

I know this has been asked a lot but I can't find no other method that does not relate to num_rows I basically want to see if a record a exist in the database in a **if else statement** and in other words I don't mind using it but for personal complicated reasons I need to stay away from that because it conflicts on other things I want to add down the road. So this is my code example is there another way to do this with out using mysqli_num_rows?

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='angel';
$password='1234';
$db_name='test';

$connect= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db_name);

$query="SELECT*FROM members WHERE first_name='bob'";

$result= $connect->query($query);

if($result->num_rows >0){
echo 'Exist';
}

else{
    echo 'Does not exist';
}
?>
```

Comment: Do a COUNT in the query?

Comment: `SELECT id FROM members WHERE first_name='bob'`, check if an id is returned

Comment: " I need to stay away from that because it conflicts on other things I want to add down the road." sounds like an imposibility btw

Comment: I need to stay way from anything that is not based on changing that $query  variable I was wondering if there is a way to do this based on a if and else statement not num_rows related

Comment: in any case, you still need to use `if/else`, so I for one am questioning that.

Comment: So, you can't use number of rows and you can't change the query. Can you do two queries?

Answer (score 1):

just to fill in the options pool

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE first_name='bob'";
```

then check you get an id returned; assuming the table has an `id` column, if not just use another one

Comment: Thanks @rtfm for your response Well I need the all symbol so I can output more things. Do you know how to do this in a if else statement with out changing the $query variable? And with out using num_rows?

Comment: I'm not interested in helping you, you have a poor attitude.

Comment: Dude you started it your just very sensitive when it comes to things like this it's up to you if you want to help still if you want but I did appreciate your effort in trying to help me out tho you just got carried a way when you said high horse do what you want I hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You could issue a separate query where all you do is count the results:

```
$getCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `MemberCount` FROM members WHERE first_name='bob'";
```

Then use the results to determine your program's path.